# Trying to keep owl carousel and side image on same line

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am setting up a basic owl carousel with an image next to it, but every time I make the page smaller, it drops the carousel to the line below it.  This is where I'm at right now:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div>
          TEST
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="owl-carousel">
          <div> Your Content </div>
          <div> Your Content </div>
          <div> Your Content </div>
          <div> Your Content </div>
          <div> Your Content </div>
          <div> Your Content </div>
          <div> Your Content </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the js is very vanilla, no css yet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin: 10,
    items: 3,
    dots: false
  });
});
```

How can I force the two divs to stay fixed and in equal proportion?  The real goal is to have one image that floats and then three next to it that scroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add classes to cols for xs devices:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3">

<div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
```

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/9OYto5qAcg4LDPguDQGu?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, nice simple solution.  How would I go about ensuring that as the screen gets larger and smaller they maintain the same height?

Comment: @Rob why not to set height explicitly

Comment: well i have four images, three are a carousel rotating and one is fixed.  When I adjust the height I get a little bit of variation between the three and the one.

Comment: @Rob sorry, i didn't get what is needed. What is "the same height"? Could not you resize images to one size? Could you make plunk, fiddle or whatever with example